# Caching in iOS network calls?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm making some network calls in my iPhone app, and I've noticed that they're behaving as if the response is being cached.  For example, if I press a button to download something that is nontrivial in size (and thus will result in a perceptive delay when downloading), it behaves as expected the first time and takes a second or two.  If I repeat the process, it finishes pretty much instantly.  I've also updated some of the files it depends on server-side and refreshed from the app, and the changes don't appear.

My networking code is pretty simple, and isn't doing anything with caching.  It's essentially a convenience wrapper around `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:...` along with some logging and logic to make sure the system network activity indicator is showing when requests are outstanding.  See [here](https://github.com/tomhamming/gcf/blob/master/GCF/GCF/GCFNetworkUtility.m) for complete details (GitHub link).

Is my guess of caching a valid guess for this behavior?  If so, could it be happening on the device, and can I disable it?  I want my data to actually refresh when I want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you setting the cache policy on your `NSURLRequest`?

```
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:90];
```

Take a look at the [NSURLRequest Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and look at the `NSURLRequestCachePolicy` section for different caching policies you can use.

Comment: `cachePolicy` is read-only? According to the documentation, it isn't read-only. Maybe try to initialize your `NSURLRequest` using `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`.

Comment: Both the documentation you link to (which is for OS X) and the iOS version of the same document say that `cachePolicy` "returns the receiver's cache policy."  I don't see a reference to it not being read-only.  But I will try the other init method.

Comment: Well this is embarassing, but you're right about the `cachePolicy` being read-only for `NSURLRequest`. I was thinking about `NSMutableURLRequest`, for which the `cachePolicy` is not read-only.